# Use token ranges to delete billions of Cassandra records using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Over half of the records in my 15TB Cassandra table are now obsolete and I want to delete them. I've written a Spark job for it but it seems fragile and usually dies with timeout errors (no mention of tombstones). So I'd like to scan the table in a series of smaller jobs, each processing a distinct and limited part of the table (thus hopefully avoiding dreaded tombstone problems). Unfortunately with my index I can't query for exactly the obsolete records, so I have to check them all. My intended approach is to select WHERE TOKEN(partition_key) > M AND TOKEN(partition_key) < N and choose a series of M,N to work my way through the table. Alas, Spark seems to have a similar idea, and so I get this error:

Exception during preparation of SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE token("context", "itemid") > ? AND token("context", "itemid") <= ? AND token(context, itemid) > 9200000005000000000 AND token(context, itemid) < 9223372036854775807 ALLOW FILTERING: More than one restriction was found for the start bound on context, itemid

I'm pretty sure that the first two conditions are being inject by Spark. I don't know where the ALLOW FILTERING is coming from.

This index obviously wasn't designed with this purge operation in mind. And at some point I might bite the bullet and migrate to a copied table sans the obsolete records. But I'd like to do this purge in-place, if feasible.

Comment: are deleting by partition key or by primary key? can you talk more about deletion condition?

Comment: If possible truncate the table and repopulate the table with required data. I always try to avoid tombstones

Comment: I'm deleting by (context, itemid), which is the partition key.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you.

Reference: https://community.datastax.com/questions/881/best-way-to-delete-1000s-of-partitions-with-spark.html

spark.sparkContext.cassandraTable(KS, T) //Full table scan

.select("run_date", "entity_type", "rank_offset") // Prune only our PK columns

.filter( ) // Do a Spark Side filtering here (No C* Pushdown)

.deleteFromCassandra(KS, T)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).